# Passing event data to jQuery live handler

Tags: jquery

I ran into a problem when I try to pass event data to jQuery live function. Basically, I have a table generated with many rows and each row data is encapsulated by an object, let's just call is "tbRow". I'd like register a live function on each row, and when you click on it, it will act differently based on the row data. The way I am structuring the code is as follows:

```
MYAPP.prototype.actions = function (tbRow) {
   var output = "<div class="select"><a href="#"> Select this row </a></div>"
   $('div.select').live('click', {tbRow: tbRow}, function() {
       console.log(e.data.tbRow.id + "is selected");
       /// do something else
   });
   return output;
};
```

The output returned by this function is used to construct the actual table, and at the same time, a live function is registered for that row to respond to the click action. The print for id (assuming each row has a unique ID) is just for checking I am selecting the right row.

The problem I ran into is that every row I select now carry the ID of FIRST row, it appears only the first one gets registered properly. One way I can think of to resolve it is, to make a concatenated string with row ID, such that:

```
$('div.select_RowID1").live( .... )
```

However, I am not sure if this will work or right approach.

Thanks in advance for help.

Oliver

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be using jQuery live in a way that is making it more difficult than necessary. You can just do this:

```
$('table.live tr').live('click', function(evt){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Here I have added a 'live' class to the table. This binds the click event to all current and all future 'tr' elements. The $(this) and evt parameter will tell you which row was clicked.

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/yyekt/

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: @Bob, similar to my above comment. Index is not the only parameter I want to access in live function. The row object was handed down from server side one by one, and I don't have a array that I can access to it just based on the index. thx

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using live will cause multiple click events to be bound to each div.select.  One each for the number of times you call the function.

Try this.  It uses the jQuery index() function to retrieve the index of the row relative to the other rows.

```
$('div.select').live('click',
  function() {   
    console.log( $(this).index() + " is selected");
   /// do something else
});

function makerow(tbRow) {
   var output = '<div class="select"><a href="#"> Select this row </a></div>'

   return output;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMH/mLW6R/1/

Edit:  Updated example

```
function makerow(tbRow) {
   var output = '<div id="select' + tbRow.id + '" class="select"><a href="#"> Select this row </a></div>'
   $( "#body" ).append( output );
   $( "div.select#select" + tbRow.id )
       .bind( 'click',
              function() {
                  console.log( tbRow.id );
              }
            );
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMH/UF4tD/1/

Comment: hmm ... this way, I don't have access to tbRow object anymore within live function, index is not the only data I need for doing something else. thanks the reply.

Comment: @Oliver Then bind a click event for each row as you add it to the document instead of using live.  Each event will get the correct copy of tbRow.